# python subprocess.Popen delaying command when in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

When I embed this function:

```
def RunCommand(self, command):
   try:
      p = subprocess.Popen(command)
      stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
   except OSError, e: raise RuntimeError, "Error while executing: '%s': %s" % (" ".join( cmd ),e,)
```

My code is delayed when it is a function in a class.

If I remove the class and just execute the command in either the interpeter or without the class controlling it, it executes the command without a delay.

Is the class causing it to wait or hang for some reason?

I also noticed the same thing happening with os.popen which I tested just for giggles to see if it was the subprocess module or not

Comment: could you provide a [*minimal* complete code example that shows the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Try a dummy command first e.g., `check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'platform'])` and see that it works. Then create minimal class with a method that just prints something and make sure that it works. Then replace the print statement with the `check_call()` and make sure that it works. If it stops working; post the code here.

Comment: you don't need to use `.communicate()` if all stdin/stdout/stderr parameter to Popen are not `PIPE`; you could use `p.wait()` or better yet `subprocess.check_call`.

Comment: I resolved it to importing a library : import customlibrary as custom .. but not sure why that would cause two different executions of executing subprocess

Comment: import in Python may execute arbitrary code so it doesn't narrow down the issue much. If you can't post a minimal complete code example here then make it for yourself, [read the link for the explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)